# Json function call in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

I have issue with $.getJSON() method. My method looks like

```
 $.getJSON("/admin/program/GetCitiesViaJson/" + $('#Product_ProductContactDetail_StateId').val(), null, function (data) {
            data = $.map(data, function (item, a) {
                return "<option value=" + item.Value + ">" + item.Text + "</option>";
            });
            $("#Product_ProductContactDetail_CityId").html(data.join(""));
            $('#cityLoader').attr("style", "display:none;");
        });
```

This works fine on local but when i deploy it on my production it doesn't work.
The production url has virtual directory which I guess creating issue (http://aaaa.com/en-us/admin/program).

Any help appreciated.

Comment: try it with Full url `http://aaaaa.com/en-us/admin...`

Comment: @Furqan I can't do that since same code base will be used for many instances e.g. en-uk, en-in...

Comment: just test if your call is working with full link or not? then u might know that u are mistaking in forming URL.

Comment: @Furqan it does work with /en-us/admin/programs, so for sure it's issue with url part (en-us)

Comment: just try giving the webmethod name only in Url i-e `GetCitiesViaJson`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem stands on your admin directory.

if your page was on "www.mysite.com/en-us/" the following is 
"/admin/program/..." = "http://www.mysite.com/admin/program/...."

"admin/program/..." = 'http://www.mysite.com/en-us/admin/....'

(the important change to the previous path is that the leading "/" is removed in order to make it a relative path)

Answer (score 0):

Use Firefox with Firebug extension. Open Firebug console (F12) and enable the Net tab. Now invoke your json call and examine the Request / Response headers.